# How does Prototype Delegation Based model work in Python?

Tags: python, oop, delegates, delegation

I used to think that the python follows a ''[Class Based Inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class-based_programming) only (maybe my limited knowledge). But after reading JavaScript which shows the '' [Prototype Delegation Based Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming), I realized that even python shows some features of prototype based implementations

```
class A(object):

  def __init__(self, a):
    self.a = a

  def square(self):
    return self.a * self.a

a = A(10)
print(a.a) #10

A.b = 20 # a new Property of the class
print(a.b) # 20 - available via "delegation" for the "a" instance
```

Also Just like in prototype based model it is possible to change prototype  of an object at runtime.

```
class B(object):
  """ Empty class B"""
  pass

b = B() # an instance of the class B
b.__class__ = A # changing class (prototype) dynamically
print (b.__dict__) # {}
b.a = 20 # create a new property

print(b.square()) # 400 - method of the class A is available
```

Even when i delete the explicit reference to class A

```
del A # deleting the explicit reference on classes
# print(A) --> error
```

The methods of Class A are still Available for Object b

```
print(b.square()) # 400
```

Also when i write `b.__class__ = A`

```
print(b.__class__) #<class '__main__.A'>
```

What i'm saying is current instance is a reference to the `type A` Right ?
Because when i print

```
print(A.__class__) # <type 'type'>
```

meaning A is a reference to type type.

**Since everything in python is an object and i've never created any Object of `A` explicitly. Does This delegation model creates the Object Of `A` Implicitly ? If not then how does this model work ? also Does the object `b` maintain the implicit reference to A or object of A in case it creates an Object as asked above ?**

Comment: Since everything is an object. You can access the members functions without even creating the Object. Read MetaClasses in Python will make things much clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since everything in python is an object and i've never created any Object of A explicitly. Does This delegation model creates the Object Of A Implicitly ?

No.

> If not then how does this model work ?

Each object knows its class (which you can change).  Attribute lookup happens dynamically: every time you try to access an attribute (including a method like `.square()`), Python first looks to see if the instance has the attribute itself, then looks at whatever `__class__` the instance has at that moment, and looks there.

> Does the object b maintain the implicit reference to A or object of A in case it creates an Object as asked above ?

When you did `b.__class__ = A`, you explicitly gave `b` a reference to `A`.  Note that `del A` does *not* delete the class called A; it deletes the *name* `A`.  Since there is another reference to this class (namely `b.__class__`), the class still exists and all lookups will happen as usual.

The way it basically works in Python is that each object has a list its superclasses, and those are checked in order every time you try to access an attribute of the object.  You can change that list (by assigning to `__class__`, or even by changing the `__bases__` attribute of its class or superclasses).

I'm not quite sure what you think this has to do with prototypal inheritance.  The main thing about prototypal inheritance is that there isn't a distinction between classes and instances; you can create an "instance" directly from any other instance.  This isn't really how Python works because classes and their instances have different behavior and you can't straightforwardly "clone" an instance in the same way you create an instance from a class.

Comment: Much needed Clarification :)

Answer (score 0):

The underlying mechanism by which a class shares its
attributes is as follows.
When you access an attribute, the value may come from several different places.
The instance is checked first and if nothing is known, the search moves to the
instance’s class instead and then up the inheritance 
chain. For example, `obj.attr` may be the `attr` attribute of the instance `obj` if it is set in the `__init__` or later dynamically else `attr` in the class definition(typical of methods).

So if you do `obj.__class__ = A`, you make it to refer to attributes of A, which are objects in memory. `del A` makes the name `A` unusable, but **an object is garbage collected only if it becomes unreachable**. `A` is unreachable now, but not it's attrs as they can be reached via `obj`.